# Running and managing nodejs applications on single server

Tags: node.js

Is there a good way to run and manage multiple nodejs apps on a single server?

I've been looking at [haibu](https://github.com/nodejitsu/haibu) and [nodester](https://github.com/nodester/nodester), but they seem a little complex for what I am trying to do.

I also was looking at [forever](https://github.com/nodejitsu/forever) and I think that may work with the config file and web gui, but I am not sure how I am going to handle passing the port information via ENV or arguments.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what the scope of your projects are, but would it be an option to utilize per-app site config files? You could specify ports for each app in a "siteConfig.js" file and import it into your server file, which is one way to organize things (see https://github.com/mape/node-express-boilerplate).  That might handle the port part but wouldn't necessarily give you a management solution for all the apps.

Comment: Let me explain my workflow. On our server we run Apache and I am going to set up a reverse proxy for every node app we develop. For now these are low traffic applications so I want to run them on the same server.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I use [Supervisord](http://supervisord.org/) & [Monit](http://mmonit.com/monit/), more details and configuration example here: [Process Management at Bringr](http://blog.fgribreau.com/2012/03/process-management-at-bringr.html).

Moreover you can specify environnement variable directly from the supervisord configuration file (see [sub-process environment](http://supervisord.org/subprocess.html#subprocess-environment)). But I personally prefer to add these variables directly inside a ~/.bashrc on each machine.

If the port number isn't going to change for each application (but change between production & development environment). I'll recommend to specify them inside a config.json (or directly inside package.json). And the config.json will contain a different port number for each application depending on the environnement:

```
{
 myapp:{
  production:{port:8080},
  development:{port:3000}
 }
}
```

And inside `myapp.js`:

```
 var config = require('./config');
 app.listen(config.myapp[process.env.NODE_ENV].port)
```

With `process.env.NODE_ENV` declared in ~/.bashrc.

Comment: Thanks for writing that blog post, it is very detailed. So would you manage ports in the supervisord config:  [program:myapp] command=node myapp.js 3000, [program:myapp2] command=node myapp.js 3001, etc?

Comment: Answer edited, hope it answer your question. I personally prefer to keep the supervisord configuration file as small as possible and keep the changing bits/env. variables in *.json config files.

Answer (score 3):

I wrote an app **nodegod** that I use for a handful deployments of maybe 10 apps each.

- **[nodegod](https://github.com/haraldrudell/nodegod)** reads an app list from json. It has an internal state machine for each app that handles the app life cycle in a safe manner including restarts, and the web page features stop/start/debug.
- The web interface uses web sockets, so that you can manage remote servers over **ssh**.
- As you deploy over **rsync**, apps restart automatically.
- Because **nodegod** monitors the stdout of other apps, you can capture an app's final breath like segfault and malloc errors.
- I use a fork of **http-proxy** in front of a slew of express instances, so any number of apps can share a single server port per dns for both http and web sockets.

I wrote a **[haraldops](https://github.com/haraldrudell/haraldops)** module to read app configuration from outside the source tree. With that you can monitor and get emails whenever something's up with an app.

App configurations I keep in a git repo in the file system.

It's not rocket science, and it all fits very nicely together. Only **node** and **json**: SIMPLE gets more done.

Answer (score 1):

If your server has upstart, just use it. I have no luck with forever and similar.
If you want to proceed with upstart, [roco](https://github.com/1602/roco) would be nice as deployment solution:

```
roco deploy:setup:upstart
roco deploy
```

Comment: Oh so in the roco script I would just define all the ports?

Comment: Yes, describe everything you need: at least port and server name(s).

Answer (score 1):

We're constantly trying to improve `forever` and `haibu` at Nodejitsu. Seems like the approach you're looking for here is a `.forever` configuration file for complex options. This feature has been on our backlog for a while now

https://github.com/nodejitsu/forever/issues/124

Check back. I consider it pretty high priority after the next round of performance improvements.

Comment: It's good to know that `forever` is still being supported! The `npm` package hasn't been updated in a while, unless I've missed it somehow. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for that input. So would it be optimal to create a management script which would generate the .forever config in each application?

Answer (score 0):

These days I've taken to using [dokku](https://github.com/progrium/dokku) which is a OSS clone of heroku. Deploying is as simple as making sure your package.json contains a start script. For example:

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "node index.js"
}
```

[Sample App](https://github.com/heroku/node-js-sample)