# Why is forever not working to keep my nodejs process running after I logout?

Tags: node.js, ssh, forever

I set up an Ubuntu Server in my home for the purpose of hosting a web application served by nodejs.  I have a connect app on my server.  When I ssh in and just do something like

```
node app.js &> server.log &
logout
```

Then after I logout the server is like put on hold, and it will not serve any requests, but when I ssh back in it starts to serve requests again.

So it looks like the forever package is designed to solve this problem.  So installed forever and am doing this:

```
forever start -al forever.log -ao serverout.log -ae servererror.log app.js
```

I get the same results from this command.  My server will serve requests while I'm ssh'ed in, but once I logout my server stops serving requests.  What else can I do to troubleshoot this?

Comment: can you try running your server in a `screen` session, or in `byobu`?

Comment: I have tried screen, but my screen session ends when I logout.  I have not try byobu yet though.  I have also tried nohup and haven't been able to use that successfully.

Comment: Did you find the answer for this? I am also facing the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using `cron`. You can run `crontab` in bash with no options to get the cron configuration for your account. You may need root access, and then have to specify the user account using the -u option. See `man crontab` for more information about your distribution's implementation.

I'm sure there are better out there, but [this](http://www.unixgeeks.org/security/newbie/unix/cron-1.html) is a decent tutorial on cron's grammar.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use Forever for this but production-ready tools like [Supervisord](http://supervisord.org) with Monit, see [Running and managing nodejs applications on single server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9561475/running-and-managing-nodejs-applications-on-single-server/9584074#9584074).

For each of your application just create a Supervisor configuration file like this:

```
[program:myapp]
command=node myapp.js                   ; the program (relative uses PATH, can take args)
directory=/www/app/                     ; directory to cwd to before exec (def no cwd)
process_name=myapp                      ; process_name expr (default %(program_name)s)
autorestart=true                        ; whether/when to restart (default: unexpected)
startsecs=1                             ; number of secs prog must stay running (def. 1)
stopwaitsecs=10                         ; max num secs to wait b4 SIGKILL (default 10)
stdout_logfile=/var/log/myapp.log       ; stdout log path, NONE for none default AUTO
stderr_logfile=/var/log/myapp.err.log   ; stderr log path, NONE for none default AUTO
```

More informations: [NodeJS process management at Brin.gr](http://blog.fgribreau.com/2012/03/process-management-at-bringr.html).